# sharing $scope.data between 2 different function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
getTopicContent.request().finally(function(){
    $scope.loader= false;
}).then(function(response){
    $scope.threadContent = response.data;


})


$scope.loadPages = function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.threadContent.totalPages);
}
```

It returned threadContent of undefined. getTopicContent is the service, but I expect $scope.threadContent can be shared with $scope.loadPages function?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading content asynchronously, you can't expect data to be available in synchronous manner. `loadPages` function should rely on promis resolution before accessing data. For example you can rewrite you code this way:

```
function getContent() {
    return getTopicContent.request().then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }).finally(function () {
        $scope.loader = false;
    });
}

$scope.loadPages = function ($scope) {
    getContent().then(function(data) {
        $scope.threadContent = data;
        console.log($scope.threadContent.totalPages);
    });
}
```

Also read this related problem [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Comment: I got an undefined is not a function error with your code.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be `getContent().then`. Updated code in answer.

Comment: the flow and concept that you suggested make sense but I wonder why it says undefined function.

Comment: Because the code I posted was `getContent.then(...)` while it should be `getContent().then(...)`. Just try updated code in the answer.

Comment: but I'm getting this  TypeError: Cannot read property 'threadContent' of undefined

Comment: Just a thought: Shouldn't it be `return getTopicContent.request();` request() is returning the promise object, so you don't need then() on both getTopicContent.request() _and_ getContent().  The change being that the then/finally logic you have inside getContent() would be inside loadPage().  Not sure if that's desirable for what you're looking to do though.

Comment: Ops, the problem is that I forgot to return data from `then`. See updated code for better approach.